# Android dual screen display

Tags: android, multiple-monitors

Is android supports dual screen display?. If then how to do this?. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Android SDK doesn't natively support dual screens.  There's a new dual-screen Android phone that was recently announced, but it uses a proprietary API to access both screens.

http://www.sprintusers.com/the-big-announcement/

That doesn't mean it won't be officially supported eventually, but it's not yet.

Comment: Here is a link to Sprint's developer site which includes information on the dual screen Kyocera Echo:  http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/mobile_platforms/android/android.jsp

Answer (score 1):

here's an android phone with dual screen

http://www.thetechherald.com/article.php/201106/6789/Android-powered-Echo-is-world-s-first-dual-screen-smartphone

but I don't think dual screen is a standard ability of android - ie, I suspect that this manufacture modified android to achieve this.